# Port Forwarding with multiple routers not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I've been trying to port-forward to set up a Minecraft server, but it doesn't seem to be working. When we had a single router setup the process was straightforward, but with multiple routers I can't seem to get the port to open.

Port forwarding settings for the modem / first router (`192.168.8.2` is the IP address of the second router):

[image: Port forwarding settings for the modem / first router]

Port forwarding settings for the second router (`192.168.0.183` is the IP address of the computer hosting the server):

[image: Port forwarding settings for the second router]

Based on all the tutorials I've found online, this seems to be the right approach. However, the ports remain closed. I've tried restarting both routers multiple times, to no avail.

What can be the problem? How to make this work?

Comment: Is the extra modem/router required because you changed the ISP maybe? If so then please make sure you're not behind a [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://superuser.com/a/1442000/432690) now.

Comment: I can't find that information in the admin page of either router. Where would it be?

Comment: When you said "`192.168.8.2` is the IP address of the second router", you meant the IP address of its WAN interface, the address visible from the first router, right? Now we're after the same thing for the first router: the IP address on its WAN (or equivalent) interface, the address visible from the ISP's network.

Comment: What are your netmasks?