# Not able to access my server using public IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, hosting

I am using TP Link router and local internet provider GTPL. I have server on which I am hosting my website but not able to access it using public ip. I am able to access in same lan with local ip like

```
http://10.167.53.249:8080/
http://192.168.0.106:8080/
**But not with below**
http://103.250.136.166:8080/
```

Please see my router configurations in following screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Describe in your comments what you have done with port forwarding. Don't let us figure out what the screenshot says.

Comment: What IP is the server binding to?

Comment: Another: [Is my router's IP address really public?](https://superuser.com/q/1441998/432690)

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2240145-cannot-access-public-ip-while-connected-locally

Answer (score 3):

The public IP address is not yours; it's shared between multiple customers. In other words, you're behind CGNAT (Carrier-grade NAT) and your network is *not* reachable from the outside.

Several results on Google confirm that GTPL has been using CGNAT for the last several years.

(If the address were really yours, generally it would show up in the router's "Status" page – you wouldn't be seeing a second "private" address there!)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of several other threads but I don't have the energy to search for a good "canonical" answer if there is one