# Port Forwarding to eth1 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi setup with two wired ethernet connections eth0 and eth1. I am having problems port forwarding to the pi on eth1.

Interface eth0 has address 192.168.**1**.4 with a gateway of 192.168.1.254 which is a router/ADSL modem.

Interface eth1 has address 192.168.**2**.4 with a gateway of 192.168.2.254 which is a router/4G modem.

In the ADSL routerI have port forwarding rules so that I can connect to the Pi from the Internet. I forward 22 for SSH and 80 for an apache webserver running on the pi. These forward to 192.168.1.4 and work as expected.

On the 4G Router I have setup the same port forwarding rules but to forward this time to 192.168.2.4 but this does not work. I can access SSH and the webserver from the 198.168.2.* network but not via port forwarding through the 4G router.

Is there some other configuration needed on the pi to allow this to work on eth1?

Comment: Most mobile networks use their own NAT due to IPv4 exhaustion and many also firewall incoming connections. This prevents port forwarding working.

Comment: [Possibly CGNAT](https://superuser.com/a/1442000/432690).