# I tried everything to connect ssh via internet but nothing is working

Tags: ssh

IDK why I can't connect to SSH over the internet.
I added port forwarding rules and windows firewall rules but still, I can't connect to SSH over the internet. My public IP is static and it doesn't change so often. After doing some research I came to know that My isp blocking some ports like 21,22,23 etc.. so I took other ports like 16123 and 10122 but still, I can't connect. I added 16123 as a wan port, 22 as a local port, and routed them to my machine where the SSH server is listening on port 22. Both ports are opened in windows firewall and I am using Kaspersky internet security. I think I gave the required info and Thank you for helping.

Note: I used Freesshd for ssh server on windows.

Comment: Check this: [*Is my router's IP address really public?*](https://superuser.com/a/1442000/432690) What is the conclusion? If the addresses match then make sure you [test from the outside, not from within your LAN](https://superuser.com/a/135379/432690).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the port redirection is O.K. in your router (doublecheck that) and that the SSH service is up and running listening on port 22, I would just turn off The AV and firewall for some seconds and try to login.

I have had bad experiences with that AV silently dropping traffic before.

Run this checklist:

1 - Check the SSH service is indeed running.

2 - Use some scanner to scan port 22 from the very same Windows box.

3 - If you don't see port 22 as open, turn off the AV and try again.

4 - If step 3 fails, turn the firewall off and try again.

5 - If step 4 fails, then the service is not running or there's some additional issue. Check the SSHD service configuration and make sure that the service is listening in the IP you want. That is configurable and for some reason it could be listening in IPv6 only per instance or in some other configured IP. Pay special attention to the message it spits when loaded, as it will generally offer details on the IPs it is listening on.

6 - I would just disable IPv6 if you happen to have it configured. It's generally not very useful in a LAN.

Comment: It is not working bro. I turned off AV and tried again but still, it is saying connection refused. The port is not opened when I checked with the port checking website but I opened the port in the windows firewall.